# escape the word in regexp

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string like this

```
 $str = '"filename","lf","$data","{ }",0';
```

How to remove all `"` from the string?
I tried to use this kind of regexp:

```
 $str =~ s/"(.+?)"//s;
```

It should match the word and remove `"`-s

Comment: No, it doest remove second ", I have tried that already

Comment: `s/"//g` is simpler. But I you could do it as `s/"(.*?)"/$1/g` which is what I think you were trying to do,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do it like this   `$string =~ s/\"//g;`

Comment: I think a `/` is missing. This one worked for me `$str =~ s/\"//g;`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$str` looks lke you're dealing with a CSV file.  Saddam's answer will work for most cases of course, but if you're really working with a .csv file, then I suggest that you use an actual parser like [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV).  That way if there are commas embedded in your double quoted valeus, they'll be handled properly:

```
use Text::CSV;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

my $str = '"filename","lf","$data","{ }",0';

$csv->parse($str);
my @columns = $csv->fields(); 

use Data::Dump;
dd \@columns;
```

Comment: @Rocker Then I strongly suggest that you use an actual cvs parser like I demonstrated above.  You might need to install the cpan module, but you're going to save yourself a lot of potential grief in the long run versus if you hack it.